# docusign REST api - Get tab info for a recipient call - Signer group issue

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

**Issue:**

Unable to retrieve the tab information associated with a signing group

**Steps to recreate it:**

1. Send an envelope to a signer group with at-least one tag ( I used signature tag) associated to that group.
2. Before you view the envelope, use below api call to retrieve tab information of a recipient ( recipient is a Signer group - in this case)

`https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/accountId/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients/1/tabs?include_anchor_tab_locations=true
// In my envelope recipient Id for signer group is 1`

3. The response will be

> [Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
>
> "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
>
> "message": "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource."

**My research:** The api call seems to work fine after any person from that signing group viewed the envelope. The status for the response is then `200`.

However, I need to perform data manipulations on that signing group's recipient tab way before the envelope reached that signing group in the routing order. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

try
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/accountId/envelopes/envelopeId/recipients?include_tabs=true

include_tabs, When set to true, the tab information associated with the recipient is included in the response.

Comment: Yep, that's a work-around. I've called technical support about why my original api call in the question was failing when the recipient is a signer group. They said that it was a bug from their end.